# A novel where an alien races "helps" Earth, but it as a part of a galactic poker game

Tags: story-identification, aliens, soft-sci-fi

Basically the plot goes like this (As far as I can remember).  The Earth is discovered by a group of Galactic civilizations, and is encouraged to join.

We begin to download massive amounts of information from the different civilizations, and as the story goes on, the main character (whom I believe is an ambassador for the human race) discovers that it is all a sham, and that we are part of a giant galactic poker game, with the losers being "retired", i.e. exterminated, and the information is the poker chips in the game, and we are accumulating obligations for each piece of information.

Comment: And I appreciate that the question is considered a duplicate, but I did search for it without success, and unless you search the term "dragon", you don't get the answer.

Comment: Future searchers will have another question (this one) that might match their keywords better and will direct them to first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it inside an answer to another question about 30 seconds *after* I posted my question....

David Gerrold's *Chess with a Dragon*.

It was in an answer to this question:
[Alien invasion: aliens create a game and challenge humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95363/alien-invasion-aliens-create-a-game-and-challenge-humans)

Once I found the name, then I found an answer referencing it. 
[Space Dragon Book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55052/space-dragon-book/55061#55061)

Comment: Could you link the question you found it in? Also, what made you think it's the exact same novel? (I'm asking because it may benefit future querents)

Comment: Yes, please add details. And you can accept in a bit less than 48 hours.

Comment: I was about to give that same answer!

Comment: Edited to add the method through which I found it.